# Cannot create soup from Selenium page_source?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract some data from WhoScored.com.

I'm using selenium to get the page source and then BeautifulSoup to navigate the DOM, but can't get anything from it.

Code below:

```
    #Importing the Libraries
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #For scraping

#Open the Home Page of WhoScored.com

driver =webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('https://www.whoscored.com/')

main_soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)

#print main_soup

result_tags=main_soup.select(".detailed-tournaments")

print result_tags
```

I get the result_tags as "[ ]". Can't figure out what is going wrong. I'm still a novice in Python. Please help.

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem. I tested your code and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ Can you paste excerpt of the result here ?

Comment: it is a long result. Wait a minute, I will copy/past it somewhere to internet and give you the link

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ i guess it's the output of the main_soup you're getting. The result_tags as per the code is giving []. i have commented out the line of code printing the main_soup.

Comment: No. I get output from both your `print` statements. Check [this link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/16275928/). I separated the 2 outputs by an other `print` in which I displayed my own name.

Comment: i don't get it. why it doesn't works for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111281/discussion-between-lokesh-sah-and-billal-begueradj).

Comment: Why use bs4 at all when you can use xpath and css seelctors with selenium?

Comment: I'm familiar with BS4. So it was the obvious choice.

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_class_name("detailed-tournaments")` would get the table, all you need to do is parse whatever you want from that i.e `result_tags.find_element_by_xpath("//tr")`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a case of broken parser. Couldn't get much details but below code works:

```
main_soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
```

I'm using: Python 2.7.2
BeautifulSoup 4.4.1
Selenium Version: 2.53.1

Comment: So you upgraded your BS version finally?

Comment: Yes. But the issue is something with the lxml or the default parser. Only HTML.parser works.

Comment: lxml works fine for me using Phantoms with an implicit wait to make sure the content is rendered.